# Excel - INDEX/MATCH with MAX and Criteria - Boolean logic

Tags: excel, indexing, boolean, max, match

[image]

Please see screen grab. 
 I am using Excel 2010. My result is needed in cell G4 which I will fill down to G14.
I am looking at the left table to match "Swindon" and the MAX value of "Net". So in this example, I would expect the result to be "Walters" from the "Name" column.
I am attempting to use two INDEX and a MATCH with some boolean logic on the two internal arrays on the second INDEX where it matches 1. However I cannot seem to get this formula working. Where am I going wrong? Please note: I am avoiding an array formula. 
Thanks for looking.

Comment: Post data as text so that we can copy.

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Comment: @Rory - I didn't consider this but for this question I would say it is not important as the real figures I am using will be more unique. Thanks

Comment: Why is avoiding an array formula important?

Comment: @Rory - Just a personal preference really. It's just so I can use this formula on multiple versions of Excel if needed. Currently I'm on Excel 2010 so MAXIFS wouldn't work which would have been ideal. I think the MAX is causing the trouble in this formula after some more testing but not sure how to get around it

Comment: What version of Excel doesn't support array formulas? Your current formula is essentially an array formula, you've just added the overhead of `INDEX` so you don't have to array enter it. ;)

Comment: I know the iOS mobile version wouldn't support the array formulas previously, but after just reading about it it looks like the Dynamic Arrays upgrade may have sorted this problem. Will need to check that out, thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are unique as you say then you could use MAXIFS, INDEX and MATCH:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAXIFS(D:D,C:C,F4),D:D,0))
```

Find the max value where Swindon is in column C then use this value in index match.

[image]

2010 version would be AGGREGATE instead of MAXIFS:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,D:D/(C:C=F4),1),D:D,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I think MAXIFS was introduced in 2019 though.

Comment: @Rory You are right.. I will see if I can change it then.

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Excel2010</kbd> try below array formula-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table6[Name],MATCH(MAX(IF(Table6[Location]=[@City],Table6[Net],""))&[@City],Table6[Net]&Table6[Location],0)),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

With <kbd>Excel365</kbd> you can try-

```
=@IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(Table6,Table6[Location]=[@City]),3,-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: He did specifically say he was using Excel 2010 though.

Comment: @Rory Sorry, I didn't notice that.

Comment: It might help someone else though! :)

Comment: Thanks @Harun24HR. I would like to avoid using an array formula thank you.